# Calculating the sum of a column dynamically using lag function on the same un-computed column?

Tags: sql, database

I'm trying to dynamically calculate a running total using the value in the past row:

The logic for computing dynamic_sum in the below table is : rooms + lag(dynamic_sum)

```
    Day     rooms   dynamic_sum   logic
2021-01-04    1         1        (rooms+lag(dynamic_sum) = 1+0)
2021-01-05    0         1        (rooms+lag(dynamic_sum) = 0+1)
2021-01-06    2         3        (... = 2+1)
2021-01-07   -2         1
2021-01-08    2         3
2021-01-09   -2         1
```

> Select Day, rooms, rooms + lag(dynamic_sum) OVER() AS dynamic_sum from
> ....

I'm not able to implement this since, dynamic_sum column is getting used in real time.

```
ERROR:  column "dynamic_sum" does not exist
LINE 1: select Day, rooms, rooms+lag(dynamic_sum...
                                     ^
```

Any help on how to achieve this kind of result would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I removed all inconsistent database tags. Please tag a single database only.

Comment: @TheImpaler thanks, sure will keep that in mind in future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `sum` window function:

```
select *,
sum(rooms) over(order by Day) as dynamic_sum
from table_name;
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f1cb34c680b696ce40f705dd4c54f288)

Comment: thanks @Zakaria , it worked. 
But i'm still confused as to how it did? Can you please elaborate a bit?
How is SUM function on OVER(order by day) taking the ALL windows/rows before the current row...shouldn't it just calculate the the sum of only 1 full window(where window being just an order by)? How is it taking all the prior windows as well?

Comment: @SanyamJain the behaviour of `sum(rooms) over(order by Day)` by default is the same as `sum(rooms) over(order by Day rows between unbounded preceding and current row)` (you can try it out here https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=661b70ebfb6e25d96f007d37acecbaa4).